# Typesafe resource files based on brand as well as culture (in MVC)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, resources

I have some resource files used within MVC views and also in data annotations validation attributes.

I can create renamed copies of these for different cultures and they are automatically picked up as expected but I also have a requirement to change the resource file based on brand as well. Brand is a config value.

Is this possible (keeping the type safety)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating custom cultures which works really well.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureandregioninfobuilder.cultureandregioninfobuilder.aspx